# html2pdf target="_blank"

Tags: php, html, html2pdf

Hy there

I'm using [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/en/) to convert a HTML doc into a PDF. Unfortunately if the PDF is opened inside the browser, `<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>` will be opened in the same tab. Is there a way to change it to a new window or tab?

Thanks!

Comment: it's https: not https. You can try with javascript.

Comment: @mariusz You mean `https://` ;-) with the added `//`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- correct :)

Comment: `<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com/">https.google.com</a>`, there, *fixed*. You can delete the question now; it's a typo, being *off-topic*.

Comment: Why is there a vote for *primarily opinion-based*? lol!

Comment: We're not going to be doing this "on the fly" here, are we? What isn't working now? I can't see that failing.

Comment: Nope, I added a comment to my edit and was just about to write it here. Of course this was a typo. But even with `https://` it's still opening in the same window..

Comment: @Fred-ii- inside the PDF I have the link, that should be opened in a new tab. But it is not. And I'm asking how to achieve this converting an html-doc to pdf using the html2pdf class.

Comment: @NicoMartin This may be a local issue, where the program used to open the PDF document, isn't "playing ball" as it were. Have you looked around (the web/Stack) to see if this is known behaviour?

Comment: Yes I did. But now luck. I tried with Opera, Chrome, Firefox and Edge. But I think it's more about a PDF-problem or lets say a problem converting a html into a pdf.